# How to make a live camera with Microsoft.media.ocr with bounding box overlay so that user can touch and have text to speech in UWP?

Tags: windows, uwp, ocr

I have implemented live camera and using Android text recognition and when I touch the bounding box overlay, text to speech works but in Universal windows, app cant get any documentation can anyone help how to implement in live camera OCR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIs from [`Windows.Media.Ocr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Ocr) namespace can extract text and text layout information from images. It’s designed to handle various types of images. For camera, you could capture images from the camera for recognition. You could get [`VideoFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.VideoFrame) from camera and convert to image.

More details about how to implement OCR in UWP app please reference [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/OCR). The scenario 2 provides how to capture image from camera and extract text.
More details about `MediaCapture` in UWP app please reference [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture).

For text to speech feature please try to reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/speech-interactions#text-to-speech-tts) and [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis).

If you want more additional features than `Windows.Media.Ocr` namespace, I recommend you to use [Microsoft Cognitive Services](http://%20https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/#Ocr). Check the *Analyze video in near real-time* section for more details.